# Powershell issues with parameters: 'Cannot convert value "" to type "System.Boolean"'

Tags: windows, powershell

I wrote a PowerShell utility that takes in a couple parameters, and transfers files from a source directory to a destination directory.

Initially, all was done as a single function, and worked well enough.

Before adding some features, I broke repeated logic into its own function.

Then, the **ISSUES** began.

It appears that the `Param()` variables are seeded with incorrect values. Running the script yields the following:

```
PS ...> .\photoTransfer.ps1 E:\DCIM\100OLYMP

Cannot convert value "" to type "System.Boolean". Boolean parameters accept only Boolean values and numbers, such as
$True, $False, 1 or 0.
At C:\Users\SWPhantom\Desktop\admin\photoTransfer.ps1:85 char:3
+   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position = 0, HelpMessage = "The path o ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

I can confirm that something's strange with
`Write-Output "src: $source"`, which spits out `src: True`. (Expected to be `src: E:\DCIM\100OLYMP`)

**HOWEVER**: I can get the value I expect to be passed in with an `$args[0]`.

I expect that the issue is simple, but I can't pick up on it, as this was my first foray into more... mature PowerShell scripting.

I am getting around the immediate problem by using the `$args[i]` method, but it'd be nice to not get an error message and use the seemingly Nice and orderly Params. (Especially since they seemed to work before I made the separate `Transfer` function).

Thanks!

Full code:

```
# Purpose: Transfer all photos from a memory card, to a destination folder, organized by year, month, date.
# Ensure that the Date Modified and Date Created is preserved.

function Transfer {
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0)]
    [string]$src,

    [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 1)]
    [string]$dst,    

    [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 2)]
    [string]$extension
  )

  # Look at the source directory. Enumerate files to be sent over. (Only copy .ORF/.MOV files)
  $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $src -Include $extension -Recurse
  $numberOfFiles = $files.Count

  if($numberOfFiles -eq 0) {
    return "No $extension files found in $src!"
  }

  # Give user last chance to stop program. Show them number of files and destination folder.
  Write-Output "Ensure the action is correct:"
  read-host "Copying $numberOfFiles files from $src to $dst ?`nPress Enter to continue"

  # Iteration for progress tracking.
  $iter = 1
  # Foreach file, check the Date Modified field. Make sure the destination folder has the folder structure like:
  # Drive/Photos/YYYY/MM/DD/
  # Where the YMD matches the Date Modified field of every photo.
  foreach ($file in $files) {
    $originalCreationTime = $file.LastWriteTime

    [string]$year = $file.LastWriteTime.Year
    [string]$month = $file.LastWriteTime.Month
    [string]$date = $file.LastWriteTime.Day
    
    # Add leading zero, if necessary
    if($month.length -lt 2) {
      $month = "0" + $month
    }
    if($date.length -lt 2) {
      $date = "0" + $date
    }

    # Test the path of destinationPath/YYYY/MM/DD/
    $path = $dst + "$year\$month\$date\"
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $path)) {
      if($verb) {
        Write-Output " $path"
      }

      New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $path
    }

    # The filepath exists!
    if($verb) {
      Write-Output "  ($iter/$numberOfFiles) $file -> $path"
    }
    $iter += 1

    Copy-Item $file.FullName -Destination $path

    # Fix the Creation Time
    $(Get-Item -Path "$path$($file.Name)").CreationTime=$originalCreationTime
  }

  Write-Output "`nCopying done!`n"

  # Delete items?
  Write-Output "Delete $numberOfItems items?"
  $del = read-host "Deleting copied files from $src ?`nY to continue"

  if($del -eq "Y") {
    foreach ($file in $files) {
      Remove-Item $file.FullName
    }
  }
}

Param(
  # Source Folder
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position = 0, HelpMessage = "The path of the source of the media")]
  [Alias("s")]
  [string]$source,

  # Photo Destination
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position = 1, HelpMessage = "The path of the folder you want to move photos to")]
  [Alias("pd")]
  [string]$photoDestination,

  # Video Destination
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position = 2, HelpMessage = "The path of the folder you want to move videos to")]
  [Alias("vd")]
  [string]$videoDestionation,

  # Verbosity
  [Parameter(Position = 3, HelpMessage = "Turn extra logging on or off")]
  [Alias("v")]
  [bool]$verb = $true
)

$usageHelpText = "usage:`n photoTransfer.ps1 <DriveName> <pathToDestinationRootFolder>`nex:`n .\photoTransfer.ps1 C T:\Photos"


#TODO: Solve this conundrum, where passing a via CMD
# Write-Output "Source before treatment: $($args[0])"
# Write-Output "Source before treatment: $($args[1])"
# Write-Output "Source before treatment: $($args[2])"
# Write-Output "Source before treatment: $($args[3])"
$source = $args[0]
$verb = $true



# I expect a drive name. If a ':' is missing, I add it.
if(!$source.Contains(":")) {
  $source = $source + ":"
}

# The assumption is that the photos are coming from my Olympus camera, which has the following path to the files.
# $olympusFolderPath = "DCIM\100OLYMP\"
# $source += $olympusFolderPath

# Make sure the destination path has a terminating '\'
# if(!($photoDestination -match "\\$")) {
#   $photoDestination = $photoDestination + "\"
# }

$photoDestination = "T:\Photos\"
$videoDestionation = "T:\Footage\"


# Check if the source and destination paths are valid.
if (!(Test-Path -Path $source)) {
  Write-Output "Source disk ($source) doesn't exist`n$usageHelpText"
  exit 0
}

if (!(Test-Path -Path $photoDestination)) {
  Write-Output "Destination path ($photoDestination) doesn't exist`n$usageHelpText"
  exit 0
}

if (!(Test-Path -Path $videoDestionation)) {
  Write-Output "Destination path ($videoDestionation) doesn't exist`n$usageHelpText"
  exit 0
}

Transfer $source $photoDestination "*.ORF"
Transfer $source $videoDestionation "*.MOV"
```

Comment: As in your `Write-Output` commands, force the `$args[0]` to a string: `$source = "$($args[0])"`

Comment: I'll make that change, though there's no issue with doing it without the quotes.

Comment: Try using [switch] for the v argument instead of [bool]...